# react router dom "no routes mached location" error / making components within router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am making website which has admin and user pages.

In the beginning I combined both into a single `<Routes>`

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
   // user related pages...
   <Route path="/" element={<>}/>
   <Route path="/signin" element={<>}/>
   .
   .
   .
  // admin related pages 
  <Route path="/admin" element={<>}/>
  <Route path="/admin/signin" element={<>}/>
  .
  .
  .
 </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And because the codes are getting longer in my Router.js,
I decided to make components out of them => so User.js and Admin.js

like so:

```js
<BrowerRouter>
  <User/>
  <Admin/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

in my User.js:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<>}/>
  <Route path="/signin" element={<>}/>
</Routes>
```

in my Admin.js:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/admin" element={<>}/>
  <Route path="/admin/signin" element={<>}/>
</Routes>
```

The problem: The router function works...
But I get an warning in my console:
ex.) No routes matched location ... (for each route I have set)

I googled why this happened, one person suggested using index for "/", but this didn't help...

Anyone who knows why this warning occurs?

Comment: What location is missing? What is the complete error/warning message?

Comment: so for every route i move i get a console error saying: "no routes mached location "..."  utils.ts: 716"
The route itself is working, but the console warning is super annoying

Comment: Right, but what is the *actual* route location/path the warning is complaining about? I'm going to guess it's complaining about a missing `"/"` in the `Admin` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it seems is that the `Admin` component isn't rendering a route for `"/"` since it is being rendered as the root route level. I suggest rendering both `User` and `Admin` on their own routes so the descendent routes they are rendering have correct paths and the overall path structure is maintained. Note that the root routes append a trailing `"*"` wildcard matcher to allow descendent route paths to also be matched.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/*" element={<User />} />
  <Route path="/admin/*" element={<Admin />} />
</Routes>
```

User

```
const User = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={....} />
    <Route path="signin" element={....} />
  </Routes>
);
```

Admin

```
const Admin = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={....} />
    <Route path="/signin" element={....} />
  </Routes>
);
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-no-routes-mached-location-error]

Answer (score 1):

In your index.js pls try it. Hope it would work.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
 <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
 </BrowserRouter>
```

And in App.js.

```
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

```
 <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/user" element={<User/>} />
        <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
 </Routes>
```

Comment: But i did this already, my question was how to divide User and Admin into components within Router. But thanks for the comment